# Display loading image while page loads Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I am very new to Django and need some help in some basic stuff. I have been searching high and low but for some reason cannot put it together. My use case is to have a python script execute in a view and display the result in a template. This has to happen when the page loads and without any user action. While I have been able to diplay the script output in the template in the required format (using bootstrap 3), I am unable to show an animated loading image while the script executes. Following is the Django view i have

```
def home(request):
    plist = []
    cmd = '/opt/sh/try.sh'

    ## run it ##
    #p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    stdout = os.popen(cmd)

    for i in stdout:
        plist.append(i.rstrip())

    plist = plist[1:]
    clist = []
    cmd = '/opt/sh/list_directories.sh'
    stdout = os.popen(cmd)

    for i in stdout:
        clist.append(i.rstrip())

    #html = subprocess.check_output('/opt/sh/', shell='True')
    t = loader.get_template('runningscript/output.html')
    c= Context({'plist':plist,'clist':clist})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

This takes about 15 secs to process. I tried using css-Jquery-html-javascirpt combo but i could not make it work. Following is what I have for template.

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static                       'css/custom.css' %}" />
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Apache Processes</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="se-pre-con"></div>

    <script src="{% static 'js/modernizr.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/ajax.js' %}"></script>

        <h1>The list of processes are</h1>
        {% if plist %}
            <ul>
                {% for i in plist %}
                    <li>{{ i }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
        <h1>The list of Clusters are</h1>
        {% if clist %}
            <ul>
                {% for i in clist %}
                    <li>{{ i }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

    </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
 <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>

    // Wait for window load
    $(window).load(function() {
        // Animate loader off screen
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

CSS:

```
    .no-js #loader { display: none;  }
    .js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
   .se-pre-con {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 background: url("images/Preloader_7.gif") 50% 50% no-repeat #fff;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If the preloader image is in your project's `static` folder, change the path of the image in your CSS file to `url("/static/images/Preloader_7.gif")`

Comment: I'm not sure if you know ajax or not. You just need to send a ajax request to the django server, and showing a image at the same time. Finally hide the image when your ajax request gets the data.

Comment: Not very familiar with Ajax, could you please guide me as to how to change the above simple get request into an Ajax one?

Comment: @xyres, its not like the image does not get loaded at all. the problem is that it gets loaded only after the script has finished and the response is sent back